QGIS Cannot reopen GeoJSON file after saving
I've recently encountered an unexpected issue with QGIS. When creating and editing a new GeoJSON file (collecting polygons), everything goes smoothly until I try to save. Occasionally, I receive the following error:

"Layer my_geom: Cannot reopen path/to/my_geom.geojson."

When this happens, all the polygons I've drawn disappear, and sometimes the layer cannot be reloaded into QGIS. Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any advice on how to fix it?

is this on windows? on a shared drive?

How do you create that new GeoJSON file?

it is on windows, and yes, on a shared drive. The layer was created using Layer->Create Layer->new temporary scratch layer , and after drawing some polygons I saved it as geojson and continue editing the geojson.
